# Laptop style multi-cell battery charge and power draw

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated

Basically, I'm trying to build a laptop of sorts. Long story... but I want to be able to have the same type of battery setup. I need between 14 and 24V from a multi-cell lipo pack but I want it to act just like a laptop battery would. Plug in the power adapter and it powers the whole thing plus charges the batteries. Unplug it and it automatically switches to battery power. 
I've seen a lot of battery management boards for charging multi-cell lipo packs (in series) but they all seem to be for charging the battery without any external load. 
So how do I even do that? Preferably is there some sort of pre-existing board I can use for this?

Comment: Take a look at [What kind of power management circuit do I need to embedded a rechargeable battery in my electronics project?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204981/what-kind-of-power-management-circuit-do-i-need-to-embedded-a-rechargeable-batte)

Comment: That's not for multi-cell. Or for nearly the power draw I'll need. Will be up to 150W.

Comment: It was to illustrate the principle of combining battery charging with switching between power sources. Shouldn't be hard to substitute one of the multi cell charger designs into it.